# Is it correct to have the query parameters directly after a slash in a URL?

Tags: url

Im getting a 304 redirect from **A** to **B**:

- **A** http://example.com/path?value1=a&value2=b
- **B** http://example.com/path/?value1=a&value2=b

Is **B** the correct form or is the server at fault?

Answer (score 7):

URLs representing directories are usually ended in trailing slashes, but the URL itself is filesystem-agnostic, so [both ways are correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

The trailing slash is almost certainly done by [Apache's mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). The documentation contains some points why is this a good practice. Although:

> If you don't want this effect and the reasons above don't apply to
>   you, you can turn off the redirect ...